# How to switch to a next "Entity" (Example TB or MaskedTB) on the form with a specific key press

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-framework-version

I am trying to find a solution to replicate what tab does when you are focused on a specific TextBox or MaskedTextBox, I already set my TabIndexs in order through Properties in VS

FormaNalaza is a form

```
private void FormaNalaza_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        //Switch to the next TabIndex Entity
    }
}
```

This was my solution but I couldn't figure out how to change the focus to the next Entity in the form

I tried `SelectNextControl(*The starting Entity*, 1, 0, 0, 0)`

**EDIT**

[Form Events](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5URh1.png)

[DateTimePicker Events (Its the first DataBox in the form...)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIapM.png)

[Code (2nd one works when it focused on the DTP)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yExmu.png)

IDK why but I am guessing it could be because from the start of the form there is a focus on a TB instead of the form but still that explanation is so stupid but if it works ill use it. It will take me 20min to generate methods and call a function that executes the code you provided...

keep in mind this is .NET Framework and as far as i know, it's old. I am guessing that you are using .NET Core

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Simple Implementation:

```
private void FormaNalaza_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        //Switch to the next TabIndex Entity
        SendKeys.Send("{Tab}");
    }
}
```

### Tab Order

[image]

### Output:

[image]

### Add it to the event:

[image]

Comment: yeah, I would, but I tested it RN and it didn't work for some reason :/ 
I even tried SendKeys.Send(Keys.Tab.ToString()); 
but it didn't work

Sorry for not testing it out before commenting :(

Comment: Did you add it to the `keydown` event of the corresponding control.

Comment: I added it on events of the form and yeah its on keydown event, i see that you have added it on the specific TB which means i would need to make an event on evry TB in form if i am right, will try it later, ill update you on the progress

Comment: You just need one event, select this in the `keydown` of the form.

Comment: Check the edited part of my Question, if you have any ideas feel free to share

Answer (score 0):

The tab key does this automatically, so if you are ok with pressing tab instead of enter, you can do that. Changing the TabIndex property of your entities will change the order in which tab will switch between them.

Comment: Yea but my client is used to pressing enter upon entering data in the TB so yeah...